# Проблема в терминале с установкой Gulp

Tags: node.js, gulp

Здравствуйте.Пытаюсь установить Gulp.Сейчас использую терминал PowerShell все как обычно захожу в нужную папку ввожу npm init. Выводит что нужно ввести имя я ввожу и после этого в терминале ничего писать не могу.Ну и уже когда нужно 2раз вводить имя не могу ничего писать Вот скрин [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я уже 3-4 раз пытаюсь установить Gulp.До этого с этим не было проблем была проблема с тем что Gulp не выводил в терминал Hello World из-за ошибки.
Потом вроде все правильно удалял. Спасибо за вашу помощь

Comment: No gulp file found

Comment: так тебе ясно написали: в имени не может быть заглавных букв. вместо `Myproject` введи `myproject`

Comment: @Grundy Все равно та же ошибка.Сейчас проблема с тем что у меня нет package.json а я не знаю где его получить

Comment: той же ошибки быть не может. Следовательно ошибка какая-то другая.